# an if statements blanks the output

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, filereader

I am trying to show a list of symbolized items and letting the user choose one to be deleted.

1. I write the info to a txt file.
2. I store the contents of the file in an array.
3. I print out the array.
4. The user inputs (L101 for example) and it will get deleted from
   the file.

The problem is in step (1)
I want the file to be written, if and only if the file didn't exist.
so I precede the while loop which will write to the file with

```
if(file.isFile() ==false).
```

This however seems to blank the output, as if the reader isn't able to read the file and store it in the array. why? 
P.S if I don't put an if and else statements the output is ok, it's just that it writes the file again, which I don't want to happen, I want ti to show everything except what the user typed.

Here's the code

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
    //Declaring the file
     File tempFile = new File("D:\\myTempFile.txt");
    //Declaring the writer
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
    int n=0;
    int L=1;
    //Writing to the file if it did not exist
    if(tempFile.isFile()==false) 
    {

    while(n<15 && L<3)
        {
        n++;
        writer.write("L"+L+"0"+n);
        writer.newLine();
        L++;
        writer.write("L"+L+"0"+n);
        writer.newLine();
        L++;
        writer.write("L"+L+"0"+n);
        writer.newLine();
        L=1;
        //}

    }
     writer.close(); 
     freeParkingSpaces();
    }
    //read the and store to array if the file exists
    else if(tempFile.isFile()==true)
    {
        freeParkingSpaces();
    }

}                

public static void freeParkingSpaces() throws IOException
   {
     File tempFile = new File("D:\\myTempFile.txt");
   //using try and catch to handle errors and print propriet message instead. 
    try{ 
        Scanner readSpaces; // declare scanner variable.
//reading from file that contains the available spaces and storing them into an array.
System.out.println("Please choose one of the following parking spaces: ");
System.out.println(" ");
String [] freeSpaces= new String[45]; // declaring the array.
int i=0;

//getting input from file that contains the available spaces and storing them into an    array.
readSpaces=new Scanner(new File("D://myTempFile.txt")); 
System.out.print("\t\t");

//Display the values of the array which are the available spaces.
while(i<15 && readSpaces.hasNext()){
freeSpaces[i]=readSpaces.nextLine();
System.out.print("   "+freeSpaces[i]);
i++;
}
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.print("\t\t");
while(i>=15&&i<30&&readSpaces.hasNext()){
freeSpaces[i]=readSpaces.nextLine();
System.out.print("   "+freeSpaces[i]);
i++;
}
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.print("\t\t");
while(i>=30&&i<45&&readSpaces.hasNext()){
freeSpaces[i]=readSpaces.nextLine();

System.out.print("   "+freeSpaces[i]);
i++;
}
System.out.println(" ");
readSpaces.close();

//create scanner object to hold the input of a user which is a park space.
Scanner holder5=new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Your choice:  ");
String spaceName=holder5.nextLine();

//declaring files

File inputFile=new File("D://Temporary.txt");

// creating object to read from Free_ParkingSpaces file
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
// creating object to write to the tempFile
BufferedWriter writer0=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(inputFile));
String currentLine;

while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();  
if(trimmedLine.equals(spaceName)) continue;//leave the required space by the user.
writer0.write(currentLine);   //write the lines to the tempFile.
writer0.newLine();   // start from new line.
}

writer0.close(); //close BufferedWriter Object

reader.close(); //close BufferedReader Object
tempFile.delete();  // Delete the old available spaces file.
inputFile.renameTo(tempFile); // Naming the temp file myTempFile.

System.out.println("Registration has completed successfuly");}


                                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tSorry, there's something     wrong try again!");}
                   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted over a hundred lines of code - and it's formatted in a way which is really hard to read. Could you try to reduce this to a *minimal* example that still demonstrates the problem, then format it clearly, and edit that into the question?

Answer (score 0):

`isFile()` checks if its a file (not a directory)

`exists()` checks if the file exists.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Change it.  Also, always make sure you read the docs about the method and know exactly its purpose before using it.

Note, if statements take a boolean, so `if(file.exists()){}` or `if(file.isFile()){}` is the right way

**Edit:**

Since you are still having problems getting the data into the file here is what you should do.

First, handle the `IOException`.  When you do `throws IOException` you are, basically, saying that you will handle the exception at a higher level, but main also declares that, so the exception is never caught (One of the problems when learning using an IDE and auto-corrections).

To make that happen you need to do:

1) Remove all `throws IOException`

2) Change the catch to be

```
 try{
    //...
 } catch(IOException ioe){
     ioe.printStackTrace();
 } catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tSorry, there's something     wrong try again!");
     System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tReason:"+e.getMessage());
 }
```

Doing this will show if there are any IO exceptions thrown.

You can also comment `tempFile.delete();` to inspect if the file actually has any data.  If you want to delete it all the time an create a new one do

```
public static void main (String args[])  {
   //Declaring the file
   File tempFile = new File("D:\\myTempFile.txt");

   if(!tempFile.exists()){
       tempFile.createNewFile();
   }
```

**Edit 2**

Here is a working example

```
    public static void main(String[] args){               
        try{

           File tempFile = new File("c:/testing/temp.txt");
           tempFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
           tempFile.createNewFile();

           writeToFile(tempFile);
           //readFromFile();
           //deleteFile();

        } catch(IOException ioe){
           ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void writeToFile (File file) throws IOException{

        //Declaring the writer
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        int n=0;
        int L=1;

        //Writing to the file if it did not exist
        while(n<15 && L<3) {
            n++;
            writer.write("L"+L+"0"+n);
            writer.newLine();
            L++;
            writer.write("L"+L+"0"+n);
            writer.newLine();
            L++;
            writer.write("L"+L+"0"+n);
            writer.newLine();
            L=1;
        }

        writer.close(); 
   }
```

Comment: Tried it even before
    isFile
,Same problem occurs

Comment: tempFile.isFile()==false, here you are saying if it is not a file then write, so remove it and do if tempFile.exists()

Comment: thanks, I removed isFile and did exists() instead, still nothing changed

Comment: first thank you so much for putting up with me.
so I edited the code (edited the if statement, deleted throws IOException, changed the catch in both the main and FreeParkingSpaces methods,changed "tempFile" to "pLotsFile")
But the problem persists, I ma guessing the problem is not in the main method?

Comment: The best thing you can do is trace your code.  Do one thing at a time then add the rest of the code.  First just create the file, put data in it.  End the program and check the file.  When you get this going add more code that will do the next step.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with the exception handling part. If `main` throws an exception, the exception is displayed anyway - all you've done is made the code more complicated and hidden the stack trace if anything other than an `IOException` is thrown. It was fine already. The OP's real problem is that they're creating a `FileWriter`, which creates the file immediately - at which point they can't tell whether the file existed *before* that statement or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are, definitely, correct.  I do not even remember what I was thinking of when I wrote this answer.   I do not want to delete the answer, because of your comment.  Can you, please, just write it as an answer so I can delete this.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb: It's fine to just edit your answer - that's not a problem.